# jQuery find attribute from url hash

Tags: jquery, url, hash, attributes, find

Trying to find the attribute value from a url hash.

```
// URL
http://url.com/index.html#link

// HTML
<a href="#link" rel="3">Some link</a>

// JS
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
// Need help finding attribute value from finding the anchor
var attribute = .find('#+anchor').attr('rel'); //this needs to have a value of 3
```

All help appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this:

```
$('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').attr("rel")
```

Or [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$("a").filter(function() { return this.hash == location.hash; }).attr("rel")
```

The [`.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) starting with `#` will be consistent, so no need to remove/add this back, just use it as-is.

Comment: great. now, how can I get the reverse... find a #hash from a rel?

Comment: @Jeffrey - The same type of selector, for example:  `$('a[rel="something"]').attr("href")`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('a[href=' + window.location.hash +']').attr("rel");
```

Comment: The extra space will make this not work, you're got an extra descendant selector in there.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
var attribute = $("a[href='#" + anchor + "']").attr('rel');
```